# Is there any command or app to monitor my system activity?

Tags: command-line

I'm looking for a command to use in the terminal or an application that allows me to see everything what is going on on my pc on real time like *$ xev* but not just for gui facts but for application status, or background processes.

Answer (score 11):

You should check out `gnome-system-monitor` it has all the running processes in real time as well as cpu, memory and network usage graphs(also in real time).

Answer (score 8):

`top`  or `htop` will list the running processes.. I'm not sure if it displays all of them, maybe, if you had a big enough screen. [lol]

But, if you want all the processes running, type:

`ps -ef`

Comment: jajaja right a very large screen¡¡

Comment: lol yeah.. well, you can also do CTRL+Minus to zoom out, and then resize the terminal, and you can get a lot more on the screen.

Comment: Try this: `top -b -d 00.05 -n 5 > event.log` and then see the event.log with a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Both Matt and giodamelio made good suggestions. Another good one that allows you to use it as a heads up display(and the one that I use) is `conky`. It can display CPU, Temp., Mem, Network Status, Weather, and lots more.

LifeHacker.com has an article about it here:
http://lifehacker.com/5847676/the-best-system-monitor-for-linux

Here are a few examples of how it can look.
http://www.linuxandlife.com/2011/09/beautiful-conky-linux.html

You should be able to get it in the software manager. The configuration it comes with is really basic, but as you'll see, there's a lot of ways to customise it.